# CKEditor not working properly inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ckeditor

I am having a problem with CKEditor inside an update panel in asp.net.
I have tab control on page with multiple CKEditor's i.e one ckeditor in each tab.

```
  string scriptAdd = @"var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_faqeditor']; if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); } CKEDITOR.replace('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_faqeditor');";
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "", scriptAdd, true);
```

The above code snippet helps in rendering the editor in update panel. But when a postback is done it still shows the earlier value and not the changed one i.e the editor does not reflect the changes made after the tab is changed in the update panel.

The same thing works perfectly fine without update panel.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: the error that i get when i try to sumbit form inside update panel is "i.contentWindow is null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late response on this, but the answer may be helpful to others as well.  You also need to do the following in code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, this.GetType(), "updatescript", "CKEDITOR.instances['ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_faqeditor'].updateElement();");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: CKeditor still has this issue in 2016! May I ask what do you mean by an "answer" above? That's just code.. where is the explanation as to why this worked for you? Thanks

Comment: updateElement has been depreciated and changed to updateSourceElement.  Also you may have to add - validateRequest="false" - to your @page, in addition to adding attribute - requestValidationMode="2.0"- to your web.config httpRuntime node.

Answer (score 8):

just force ckeditor to update the textarea on change :

```
var ckEditor = CKEDITOR.replace('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_faqeditor');

ckEditor.on("change", function (event) {
    event.editor.updateElement();
});
```

Comment: Now this should have been the official answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scrpM" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnshow" runat="server" Text="Show Hidden Editor" />
            <div id="divEditor" runat="server" visible="false">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plCKEditor" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>


----------


Add editor inside a div with visible="false"
and on the button click you set visible="True"
it's works fine for me
```

Comment: ??!! What is this? An answer?